# Noob C++ I dont quit understand functions and especially how to pass the read file into the struct in a function

Tags: c++, function, structure, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


struct Student{
    string name, status;
    double grade1, grade2, 
           grade3, average;
};

string getInputFileName();
string getOutputFileName();
void readStudents(vector<Student>, string);
void writeStudents(vector<Student>, string);

int main(){

    vector<Student> students;
    string inputFileName, outputFileName;

    inputFileName = getInputFileName();
    outputFileName = getOutputFileName();

    readStudents(students, inputFileName);
    writeStudents(students, outputFileName);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

string getInputFileName(void){

    string getLocation;
    cout << "Please type the location of the file"
         << " you would like to open." << endl
         << ">>";
    cin  >> getLocation;


    return getLocation;

}

string getOutputFileName(void){


    string writeLocation;
    cout << "Please type the location of the file"
         << " you would like to write to." << endl
             << ">>";
    cin  >> writeLocation;


    return writeLocation;


}

void readStudents(vector<struct Student> inputFileName){
    struct Student{
    string name, status;
    double grade1, grade2, 
       grade3, average;
    };
    vector<Student> students;
    string name;
    double grade1, grade2, grade3;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(getInputFileName());

    while(!inFile.eof()){
            inFile >> name >> grade1 >> grade2 >> grade3;
    }
}
//write from input file 
void writeStudents(vector<struct Student> outputFileName){

    struct Student{
    string name, status;
    double grade1, grade2, 
       grade3, average;
    };
    vector<Student> students;
    string name;
    double grade1, grade2, grade3;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open(getInputFileName());

    while(!outFile.eof()){
            outFile << name << grade1 << grade2 << grade3;
    }
}
```

The errors I'm getting are uninitialized variables in the 4th function. I don't know why. probably because I'm not inputting the info correctly. I want to be able to read from the user input file location and write to the user specified location while using the structure data type. Im stuck at the moment.

Comment: A couple things: try to format the code correctly so it's easier for others to read.  For example, code inside the `{...}` of a function definition should be indented by a consistent number of spaces.  Second, in your functions like `getOutputFileName` you `return` something to the caller, and then have another line (`outFile.close()`).  Don't write code like that.  Once it returns, that's the last thing it does. The compiler may be complaining about that.  Also I'm not sure you need to open and close the file in those functions.

Comment: You declare the function `readStudents` at the top of the file to take two parameters: a `vector<Student>` and a `string`, but when you implement the function, below, you change the parameters to `(vector<struct Student> inputFileName)`.  That's only one parameter, and it is mis-named.  Within that function you need to create the Student struct and add it to the vector. As it is, you're reading the fields and then forgetting about them; nothing is added to the vector.

Comment: Okay, Sorry about the indentation, I thought I did what the red box said to do. Okay I thought i always needed to close a file i opened. is the while loop correct as far as passing it through the structure?

Comment: Yes, you should close a file if you open it. But in that function, you don't need to open it either.  You open a file to read from it, or write to it. But in those functions you are not reading or writing, so no need to open and close the file. Lastly, if you do need to close something, you would close it before the `return` statement.

Comment: I see you did indent it right in the form, but stackoverflow got confused by the mix of tabs and spaces. I converted to all space characters.  Your `while` loop looks fine, but your phrase "passing it through the structure" does not make sense. In my second comment I mention the problem with those two functions.

Comment: okay so I created the struct in the function but i am confused as to how I add it to the vector. At least the program begins to run but stops doing anything after I input the read and write locations. When I said pass to the structure I meant having the file read the name then grades and put them in order. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you taking a class? There are number of things wrong with that function, and I can't go into it here any more. I suggest you get help from a TA or read a basic C++ book. (Or if you have a choice pick another language that is easier to start with than C++.)  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> The errors I'm getting are uninitialized variables in the 4th function...

I guess it's your `writeStudents` function.

There are a few things wrong.

---

This function has a declaration and a definition. These should be compatible, they aren't quite so:

```
void writeStudents(vector<Student>, string); // declaration
void writeStudents(vector<struct Student> outputFileName) {...} //definition
```

The declaration says that the functions gets 2 parameters; the definition should state the same; and it should also give names to these parameters. Here is an example definition:

```
void writeStudents(vector<Student> parameter1, string parameter2) {...}
```

There are names better than `parameter1` and `parameter2` - you already have these better names elsewhere in your code:

```
void writeStudents(vector<Student> students, string outputFileName) {...}
// equivalent definition; works the same way but easier to read
```

---

There is much useless and confusing code in your `writeStudents` function:

```
struct Student{
string name, status;
double grade1, grade2, 
   grade3, average;
};
vector<Student> students;
string name;
double grade1, grade2, grade3;
```

I guess you copied it from somewhere by mistake; the compiler tried its best to make some sense of it, but probably got confused. Just delete this code.

---

The rest should be easy.